# Unexpected output from CrossTable

Tags: r

I am using the CrossTable method from the `gmodels` package in the following code:

```
CrossTable(news_test_pred, news_raw_test$type, prop.chisq = F, prop.c = F, prop.t = F, dnn = c('predicted', 'actual'))
```

Upon executing, the output is this:

```
Total Observations in Table:  19 


             | actual 
   predicted |  negative |  positive | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
    negative |         3 |         0 |         3 | 
             |     1.000 |     0.000 |     0.158 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
    positive |         9 |         7 |        16 | 
             |     0.562 |     0.438 |     0.842 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |        12 |         7 |        19 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

My question is, if there were 12 "actual negatives" and, of which, I predicted only 3 of them correctly, why does it show 100%?

Am I not reading this cross table correctly?

Comment: Those are row probabilities below the negative and positive counts. "1.00+0.00==1" and "0.562+0.438==1" If you want percents for each "actual" rather than "predicted" value, you can flip your first two parameters.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks :).  I didn't know I could flip those.  You answer makes sense to me.  Please post and I will accept as your time permits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probabilities listed below the counts in the inner cells represent a row probability

```
 1.00+0.00 == 1
 0.562+0.438 == 1
```

This is saying that for the 3 values you predicted to be negative, all of them were actually negative.

However it sounds like you want to condition on the true value rather than the prdicted value. The easiest way it just to swap your parameters to `CrossTable`

```
CrossTable(news_raw_test$type, news_test_pred, 
    prop.chisq = F, prop.c = F, prop.t = F, 
    dnn = c('actual', 'predicted'))
```